# Correct use of concern's constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have one concern and two classes which include it. In the concern, I defined one variable. Here is the concern and the two models:

```
module UserInstance
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    ACTIVE = 'active'
  end
end

class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base

  include UserInstance

end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  include UserInstance

end
```

I'm getting this warnings:

```
/app/app/models/concerns/user_instance.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant UserInstance::ACTIVE
/app/app/models/concerns/user_instance.rb:12: warning: previous definition of ACTIVE was here
```

I guess that once it loads one class (like `Guardian`), it also loads the constant, and loading the other class tries to load the constant again, and then the warning is given. How can I avoid this without having to put the constants in the two models? Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I just came across the same bug, when trying to implement concerns.

The guide I was following also but the Constant in the included block and seemed to have no error. But my log threw me exactly the same error you have.

After some trial and error, I just removed the Constant from the block and put it outside, like:

```
module UserInstance
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

  end

  ACTIVE = 'active'
end
```

This way I could still access the Constant, but didn't get anymore errors. I'm not 100% sure that this is the right way, but it worked and I couldn't find any errors, so I will go with it.

I would like to now if this works for you too!

Comment: Yes, even on Rails 5 using concerns this seems to be the right way to do it

Comment: Not really an error, just a warning. If you're doing things right (freezing strings for example), you should have no problem with the redefinition of constants. However this is the correct way of using constants in concerns

Comment: If you want to dig deeper on the why this is, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751918/ruby-defining-constants-using-class-eval-can-be-found-only-via-const-get-but-no - Ruby blocks have lexical scope, which means when you define a constant inside the `included` block, it has the same effect as declaring it outside of it. So you actually declared only one constant, which is `UserInstance::ACTIVE`. Since ActiveSupport::Concern will call the included block when it's included, you'll be actually trying to define it again on every inclusion, hence the warning.

Comment: And just to be extra clear, the reason why you can access `Student::ACTIVE` and `Guardian::ACTIVE` is not because they were defined inside those classes by the included block and you have 2 separate constants; as mentioned, defining that constant inside the `included` block didn't change it's definition scope, which was the concern itself;  when Ruby can't find the constant in the lexical scope in `Student::ACTIVE`, it goes UP the inheritance chain, and since you included the concern in the model it will be searched, and thereby it finds `UserInstance::ACTIVE` and returns it.

Comment: This also confused me at first because defining a constant inside the `included` block looks very similar to defining a local variable inside a block; as we know, "block local variables" are an exception to the "lexical scope" rule of blocks, which means that unless they were previously defined outside the block, only the block can see those local variables; this, however, does NOT apply to constants, so if you define a constant within a block, it has the exact same effect of defining it outside of that block.

Answer (score 15):

Using `base` solved the problem for me.

```
module UserInstance
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included
  included do |base|
    base.const_set :ACTIVE, "active"

    # direct const creation in this included block will attach the const to the concern module, not the including class
    # so if you have multiple classes including the same concern, it will try to difine the same const to the same module
    # ACTIVE = "active" 

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6, this works for me.
Usecase was to flag records for something based on what attrs were updated.

```rb
module MyNameSpace
  module MyModule
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def syncable(*attrs)
        cattr_accessor(:attrs_to_sync, default: attrs)
      end
    end

    included do
      const_set(:REDIS_KEY, "mynamespace.mymodule.#{table_name}")

      after_save :enqueue_for_sync
    end

    private

    def enqueue_for_sync
      return if (saved_changes.keys.map(&:to_sym) & attrs_to_sync).empty?

      Redis.current.rpush(self.class::REDIS_KEY, id)
    end
  end
end
```