# Ruby: defining constants using class_eval can be found only via const_get but not via directly :: lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a User class:

```rb
class User
end
```

I want to define a new constant using `.class_eval`. So:

```rb
User.class_eval { AVOCADO = 'fruit' }
```

1. If I try to access it via `User::AVOCADO`, I get `uninitialized constant User::AVOCADO`, but `User.const_get(:AVOCADO)` works. Why?
2. If I define a constant inside a Rails Concern in the `included` method and include the concern in the `User` class, I can access it via the regular `::` lookup. For instance:

```rb
module FruitConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
     AVOCADO = 'fruit'
  end

end

class User
  include FruitConcern
end

User::AVOCADO
=> 'fruit'
```

However, looking up the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5aaaa1630ae9a71b3c3ecc4dc46074d678c08d67/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb) for ActiveSupport::Concern, `included` just stores that block in an instance variable (`@_included_block`), and then it's override of `append_features` will call `base.class_eval(&@_included_block)`.

So, if it's just calling `User.class_eval` with the same block, why `User::AVOCADO` works when the constant is defined inside that `included` block, but not when I call `User.class_eval { AVOCADO = 'fruit' }` directly?

3. Weirdly (see [this blog post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/constant-annoyance)), when doing `User.class_eval { AVOCADO = 'teste' }`, it seems Ruby also leaks the  constant to the top level. So:

```rb
User.const_get(:AVOCADO)
=> "fruit"
AVOCADO
=> 'fruit'
```

I know blocks have flat scopes, but the constant was NOT defined beforehand, and I expected `class_eval` to change both `self` and the `default definee` to the receiver. What is going on here? And how is this constant being defined twice, at the top-level and also in the User scope?

Answer (score 7):

When you define constants you're not assigning a constant to *self*. You're defining a constant in the current module nesting.

When you explicitly open a class or module you're also setting the module nesting:

```
module Foo
  BAR = 1
  puts Module.nesting.inspect # [Foo]
end
```

When you do `User.class_eval { AVOCADO = 'fruit' }` the module nesting is "Main" aka the global object:

```
User.class_eval do
  ADVOCADO = 'Fruit'
  puts Module.nesting.inspect # []
end
```

Blocks do not actually change the module nesting. `const_set` on the other hand defines a constant inside of another module nesting.

Ruby also isn't actually defining the constant twice. Rather when you use const_get or reference a constant without explitly using the scope resolution operator Ruby will look through the module nesting and walk the tree up to the global scope:

```
class A
end
B = 'eureka'
A.const_get(:B) # 'eureka'
```

Thats how you can reference top level constants without prefacing them with `::`. But when you use `User::ADVOCADO` you're explicitly referencing the constant inside of `User`.

When it comes to the example with the concern you have missunderstood whats happening. Is not at all about `class_eval`. You're defining the constant `FruitConcern::AVOCADO`.

When you then include `FruitConcern` into `User` you're adding `FruitConcern` onto the ancestors chain which is included in constant lookup:

```
module FruitConcern
  ADVOCADO = 'fruit'
end

class User
  include FruitConcern
end

User::ADVOCADO  # fruit
```

See:

- [Ruby modules: Include vs Prepend vs Extend](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/ruby-modules-include-vs-prepend-vs-extend-f09837a5b073)
- [Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)

Comment: Do you have an explanation why inheriting from `FruitConcern` works, but inheriting from `Object` doesn't? I failed to explain this in my answer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Its all down to the ancestors chain. If you use inheritance or `Module.include` Ruby places that constant in the ancestors chain. When it can't find a constant in the current module nesting it also looks in the ancestors chain - all the way back up to Object.

Comment: But in the OP's code, `AVOCADO` is defined in `Object`, and is *not* found.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not sure completely how to explain it. `main` is an instance of `Object`. But constants are not really defined in `Object` thus they are not really in the ancestors chain.

Comment: `Object.constants.grep(:AVOCADO) #=> [:AVOCADO]`

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right. I think the only explaination can really be found from digging into the Ruby implementation(s) of constant lookup - it may ignore constants in the top level scope when the scope resolution operator is used.

Comment: … hence my confusion :-D

Comment: @JörgWMittag it would make for some very interesting bugs though if Ruby did fall back to the global scope when you used the scope resolution operator - after all the point is getting constants in a specific nesting.

Comment: @JörgWMittag @max What a class you've both given me here. So, in reality, the third implicit scope, which is the "constant scope" is, per Conrad Irwin's article linked in this answer, the "innermost class or module statement in the code". This means that the constant I defined inside FruitConcern::included method call was actually defined in FruitConcern::AVOCADO, and since I included that concern in User, it was found because of the second rule of lookup (User's ancestors chain). However, we also found out this rule has one exception: top-level constants defined in Object when `::`is used

Comment: Exactly. I think the key thing to remember is that the Ruby core classes are written in C and not Ruby so Object, Array, Hash, Module etc do not always behave in a way that would be expected from ruby classes. For example Object probably implements its own constant lookup scheme.

Comment: Do u think class_eval not changing the module nesting can be considered a bug? I have to say this is somewhat a surprising behavior no?

Comment: @Joel_Blum hard to say. It's somewhat surprising but Ruby is still pretty consistent in that only the `class` and `module` keywords change module nesting. You can if needed use `self::FOO = 'bar'` when defining constant with `class_eval` or `module_eval`.

Answer (score 6):

There are [three implicit contexts in Ruby](https://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846):

- `self`, the "current object": the implicit receiver and the scope for instance variables.
- The *default definee*: where methods end up that are defined with `def bar` without an explicit target (i.e. *not* `def foo.bar`).
- Constant scope.

The first two are explained very well in the linked article. An article for the third one is promised in the linked article, but it never appeared. Many people have written many words about constants, but unfortunately, nobody has written an authoritative specification, similar to what yugui did for the *default definee*.

So, unfortunaly, I, too can only speculate, and thus unhelpfully add to the mountain of non-authoritative words written about this topic.

Blocks are lexically scoped in Ruby, and they capture their lexical environment. In general, that means that references *inside the block* mean exactly the same thing as outside the block, as if the block wasn't there. (The exception are of course block local variables.)

So,

```ruby
foo { AVOCADO = 'fruit' }
```

means the same thing as

```ruby
AVOCADO = 'fruit'
```

*Unless*, of course, `foo` somehow changes the context in which the block is evaluated. We know that `instance_eval` changes `self`. We know that `class_eval` changes `self` and the *default definee*. However, the important thing is: `class_eval` *does not* change the implicit constant scope.

Hence, the assignment `AVOCADO = 'fruit'` inside

```ruby
User.class_eval { AVOCADO = 'fruit' }
```

has *exactly the same meaning* as it would have, if it were outside the block:

```ruby
AVOCADO = 'fruit'
```

In other words, it has the same meaning as a constant assignment at the top-level, and as we know, at the top-level:

- `self` is the unnamed singleton object, commonly called *main*,
- the *default definee* is `Object`, with the added twist that methods become `private` by default, and
- the implicit constant scope is also `Object`.

So, `AVOCADO` gets defined in `Object`.

Which means that the following works:

```ruby
class User
  AVOCADO
end
#=> 'fruit'
```

Because constant lookup goes first lexically "outward" (where it fails in this case), then "upward" in the inheritance hierarchy, where it succeeds, because `User` implicitly is a subclass of `Object`.

```ruby
User.const_get(:AVOCADO)
#=> 'fruit'
```

also works, because that's actually the same thing as the one before, just done dynamically with reflection: it starts the constant lookup algorithm in class `User`, same as if you had written

```ruby
class User
  AVOCADO
end
```

However, this does not work:

```ruby
User::AVOCADO
```

Which, to be honest, is confusing, because `AVOCADO` *should* be inherited from `Object`.

Comment: Its not really that confusing that `User::AVOCADO` does not work. You're explicitly telling Ruby to look for the constant in `User` - and its not defined there. That is after all exactly what the scope resolution operator is supposed to do.

Comment: Except that you show at the end of your answer that it follows the inheritance chain, and thus it *should* be found in `Object`, which after all is a superclass of `User`. The thing I cannot explain is why it is inherited from `FruitConcern` but not from `Object`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ah, as for your last remark: the behavior changed in ruby 2.5.0. on Ruby 2.3.1 User::AVOCADO works  (with a warning). https://bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2.5-has-removed-top-level-constant-lookup